# WPF GridView - Dynamically binding a custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I would like to bind a List of a Player class (Representing american football players' statistics) to a GridView.
The way I represent these players (On a model level, so I could change this in the modelview) causes me a lot of trouble.

```
class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }
}

class Statistic
{
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public StatisticCategory Category { get; set; }
}

enum StatisticCategory
{
    Offense,
    Defense
}
```

I would like to Bind a list of these Players to a view which can be ordered by columns.
For Columns I would like to do the following:
Take the value of a combo box, convert it to a StatisticCategory object, then select all of the statistics in the same Category (each only once, of course) of all the players. The data bound to these columns should be the value of the statistics (if the player has the given statistic), otherwise the character '-', or something similar, representing a lack of data.

I've considered many options using online tutorials, but none seem to cover this kind of binding, I'm not even sure this is possible.

Maybe I should consider other representations of my data, if you have suggestions concerning that, it'd be appreciated aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) exposed as part of a ListView or another XAML control.

```
<DataTemplate xmlns:mylib="clr-namespace:MyLib.Players" DataType="{x:Type mylib:Player}">
    <!-- template -->
</DataTemplate>
```

This template can also be listed as a shared resource so it can be accessed from many places.

Comment: Yes, I have considered that options, the thing that I couldn't put my mind around is how would I set a DataTemplate up in such a way as I described, I mean I would still have to (declaratively) provide a binding in a ColumnName-Property name fashion, when I don't know the ColumName, and I don't have a Property to bind to it.